# android: how to start service from gallery share intent

Tags: android, android-intent, gallery, share

I am developing an app which would let users send a photo through email, without opening an email app (users just have to click on share button, and app automaticaly would send an email with photo attachment.

To achieve this I want to start service directly after choosing my app on gallery share via ... menu.

What I am doing now is creating a transparent activity and it works just fine, but it prevents users from browsing gallery until email is sent

So how could I solve this problem? I think I could create transparent activity which would start a service, but is it really the best way to achieve what i want?

EDIT (some pieces of code):

Manifest to open transparent sendactivity when using gallery share intent

```
<activity
            android:name="com.VN.PicSharer.sendActivity"
             android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
            android:label="string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

and shown piece of code is used to get data from gallery

```
public class sendActivity extends Activity {

    Context con;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        File file;
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        con = getApplicationContext();

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action)) {
            if (extras.containsKey(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)) {
                try {
//code for sending email with attachment
```

EDIT2: SOLVED. 
Changed my startActivity class to act like service activator, and in its intent put need data for attaching a picture:

```
intent = new Intent(this, SendService.class);
        Intent mIntent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = mIntent.getExtras();
        String action = mIntent.getAction();

        intent.putExtra("bundle", extras);
        intent.putExtra("string", action);

        startService(intent);

        onBackPressed();
```

In my service I have used AsyncTask to send email(because without it when sending few photos in few seconds app would freeze in a while).

Hope this could help some of you guys!

Comment: i've added some pieces of code. I will try right now to replace this activity with service, and create additional activity to call my service.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `onActivityResult` and check if the `RESULT_OK` if so then continue with the process that you wanna do.

-- after executing your process, add this to it after it finish,  this will bring up the user home screen with keeping your device running.

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
```

Comment: I don't think that will work. It will take time for javamail to return result, and I want to close my activity immediatelly (i mean, user should just click my app on gallery share and be able to instantly navigate gallery after clicking on my app intent/button.

Comment: Well, I couldn't realize your idea(just haven't understood how), but I have successfully found a workaround - from my transparent activity i have started a service with asynctask. 

And BTW, moveTaskToBack(true) somewhy sent me to homescreen, so I have just used  onBackPressed();